# Как отсортировать массив объектов по массиву значений определённого свойства?

Tags: javascript, java

Есть массив объектов:

```
messages = [
      {"id":1, "language":"ar"},
      {"id":2, "language":"en"},
      {"id":3, "language":"su"},
      {"id":4, "language":"mo"},
      {"id":5, "language":"da"}
];
```

И есть массив языков, например, он может быть таким:
sortableLanguages = ["su", "ar"];
В итоге должно отсортироваться так:

```
messages = [
      {"id":3, "language":"su"},
      {"id":1, "language":"ar"},
      {"id":2, "language":"en"},
      {"id":4, "language":"mo"},
      {"id":5, "language":"da"}
];
```

Т.е., сначала сортируется по массиву sortableLanguages, а потом остальные as is.
Дошел до такого кода:

```
messages.sort((a, b) => {
  if (sortableLanguages.indexOf(a.language) === -1) return -1;
  return sortableLanguages.indexOf(a.language) < sortableLanguages.indexOf(b.language) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Но почему-то получается всё наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
messages.sort((a, b) => {
  [ a, b ] = [ a, b ].map(n => sortableLanguages.indexOf(n.language));
  return a === -1 ? 1 : b === -1 ? -1 : a - b;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное !

Comment: @DmitryUsov если ответ решил вашу проблему — примите его (отметте как решение).